# CRM 2011 lookup attribute mapping

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to set null/blank lookup values on relationships in CRM 2011 when they open from the parental/referrential entity?

**Example**, if you create a new 1:N relationship between the entities *opportunity* and *account* holding an *agency* value. When creating a new opportunity from an account, this account is prefilled in both the potential customer lookup field and the agency lookup field.

This can easily be remedied with a javscript, clearing the field onload, but can this be done earlier, in the attribute mapping, or is it always a post-fix to correct the default action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue in Crm 4. So I suppose it still exists in 2011.

You cannot remove the relationship mapping of the primary attribute, though I've never understood why this automatically maps to fields of different relationships.

In this case you are just best off using JavaScript to perform the following logic:

If the form is in create mode and both fields contain the same value then clear the duplicated field.

This logic should ensure that it only clears the fields in this circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without Javascript.
MS CRM doesn't give you an option to counter the autofill of the mapped field. It will always be automatically filled in by the system.